# set nowplayingInfo for showing song title, artist on airplay (apple tv), not work

Tags: ios, airplay, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I have search all about the setting song info for airplay, look like simple, but I still can not make my app work well.
I use MPMoviePlayerController to play an audio.
And I have also read AirPlay overview in developer.apple.com.

I have set the following code in my view

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {return YES;}
- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [ [UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {
    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
        switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
               // [self playPauseToggle: nil]
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
                [self nextTrack: nil]
                break;
     }
}
```

and also set nowplayinginfo before playing music (have tried set this after playing music also)

```
NSMutableDictionary *airPlaySongInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [airPlaySongInfo setObject:@"hihi title"] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        [airPlaySongInfo setObject:@"hihi artist"forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
        [airPlaySongInfo setObject:@"hihi album" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
        [airPlaySongInfo setObject:albumArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
        [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:airPlaySongInfo];
```

and I have set the background mode for playing audio in plist.
but there is no title, artist and album info on my TV.
Did I miss something? or there is something conflict?

Comment: Did you find what was missing ?